# static local variable reseting itself - c

Tags: c, variables, static

I'm trying to use a static variable that I decrement on each function call but it keep resetting itself (kind of weird for a static variable):

```
int func()
{
 static int x;
 x = 5;
 x--;
 return (x);
}

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
 int x;

 x = 5;
 while (x != 0)
  {
   printf("%i\n", func());
   x--;
  }
}
```

the output is :

> 5 5 5 5 5

You must know that it's for school purpose and our teacher forbids us to declare and initialise the variable on the same line. And we can't pass it through the arguments either.

Comment: `x = 5;` -- not *it* keep resetting itselt; **you** keep resetting it!

Comment: Yes but how can I declare it without resetting itself ?

Comment: `static int x = 5;`???

Comment: Well, I can't. It's for a school purpose. Our teacher forbid the use of declaration and initialisation on the same line

Comment: That's the point of the question actually. And I can't pass it through the arguments either

Comment: Can you count up instead of down?  If you don't specify an initialisation value, it'll start at zero (because it's static).

Comment: [Cannot reproduce the claimed situation](https://ideone.com/VnKho4).

Comment: Know that at epitech you **CAN** initialize a `static` variable... And know that here you don't initialize your variable you affect it.

Comment: @stargatic yes I know I just read the norm file 2 seconds ago... Kind of dumb of me... struggling on the norm...

Comment: An initialisation is **always** with the declaration (which makes it a _definition_)! Anything else is an assignment. Either you missunderstood your teacher or he should not teach C.

Comment: @NathanSchwarz: There is no C norm! It is a standard! (If you are German, you should be aware that "Norm" and "Standard" are perfect false friends in German an English.)

Comment: I'm puzzled about the bug in your compiler that means the code produces a sequence of `5`'s.  When I try the code, it produces a sequence of `4`'s.  If you used `return x--;` instead of `x--; return x;` you'd get `5`'s returned.

Comment: If your teacher's teaching you not to initialize variables when they're defined, then they're doing you a major disservice.  Further, you can't easily resolve your problem unless you do initialize `x` in the function; if you assign to `x` on each pass through the function, you'll always get the same value back.  I suppose you could add `static int y;` and `if (y == 0) { x = 5; y = 1; }` in place of your `x = 5;` line and then you'd get more or less the result you want.  I'm not sure if the extra variable is allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't count down, count up:

```
int func(void) {
  static int x;
  return 5 - x++;
}
```

Usage:

```
for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i) {
  printf("%d\n", func());
}
```

Comment: Smart move ! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can declare and initialise a static variable and more than one line as follows:

```
static int x
= 5;
```

Comment: *"Our teacher forbid the use of declaration and initialisation on the same line"* That's the answer! :D

Comment: HAHAHA, so funny.

Answer (score 0):

Have another static  variable that checks if `x` has been previously initialized:

```
int func()
{
  static int x, initialized; /* Both initially 0 */
  if (!initialized) { x = 5; initialized = 1; }
  x--;
  ...
}
```